# How to plot a bar plot using two single values?

Tags: r, string, plot

I have an vcf file which contains a column (`df$INFO`) with Indels and SNPs, I did that to take the number of rows with each one using the package `library(stringr)`:

For INDELs:

```
 s <- str_which(df$INFO, "INDEL")
```

and then `length(s)`.

For the total of rows at INFO column:

```
 s1 <- str_which(df$INFO, "DP")
```

all rows contain `DP value` so i get the count of total rows.

For SNPs: `s2 <- length(s1) - length(s)` with that i get the count of rows that are SNPs.

The INFO column looks like a huge amount of rows for each chromosome and contains a string like:

SNP line looks like:

```
 DP=17;VDB=2.590081e-02;RPB=-6.851602e-01;SGB=-1.000416e+01;MQ0=0;AF1=0.3381;AC1=2;DP4=12,0,5,0;MQ=34;FQ=6.69;PV4=1,1,0.0017,0.22
```

INDEL line looks like:

```
 INDEL;IDV=73;IMF=0.768421;DP=246;VDB=1.803553e-02;RPB=0.000000e+00;SGB=-6.120835e+00;MQ0=0;AF1=1;AC1=6;DP4=0,0,0,5;MQ=29;FQ=-39.4
```

With that information, I want a better way to get all the number of rows for INDELs and for SNPs (I think the way i do that it's not the best) and then generate a barplot with those 2 values like:

[image]

But instead the `1` and `2` of xlab, put INDELs and SNPs

Comment: The second part: `barplot(c(s1, s2), names.arg = c("INDELs", "SNPs")`. For the first part, what do you mean by better? What is wrong with the way you are doing it now?

Comment: Hi, i tried to do `x <- c(INDELs = length(s), SNPs = s2)` and then `barplot(x, width = 1)` it works but I'm not sure if that's better or maybe i need to use names.arg

Comment: Get the number of rows of SNPs by split if the row/s does not contain "INDEL" to not use the `s1 <- str_which(df$INFO, "DP")` and then the `s2 <- length(s1) - length(s2)`. But i'm asking if u know how to get those values using another way.

Comment: To avoid `stringr` you could use `grep("DP", df$info)`